# How to hide userdefiened menu item under search menu in Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Can someone tell what is wrong with the below code. It is not working. When perspective changes it should hide respective menu item.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.search.menu?after=xxxGroup">
    <command commandId="com.xxx.udt.ui.xxxOpenFileSearchPage"
             label="XXFS"
             mnemonic="%XXXOpenFileSearchPage.mnemonic"
             icon="icons/full/search/XXXSearchDialog.png"
             helpContextId="file_search_action_context">
       <visibleWhen
                checkEnabled="false">
             <with
                   variable="com.XXX.udt.ui.serviceprovider.ShowActions">
                <equals
                      value="showAction">
                </equals>
             </with>
          </visibleWhen>
    </command>
</menuContribution>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
     <handler
           commandId="com.XXX.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage"
           class="com.XXX.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage">
     </handler>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `visibleWhen` expression to check the current perspective is something like:

```xml
<visibleWhen>
   <with     
      variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.currentPerspective">
      <equals
            value="org.eclipse.pde.ui.PDEPerspective">
      </equals>
   </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

This particular expression is testing for the Plug-in Development perspective.

Comment: I have changed visible condition but still it is not working. Menu itself is not created.

Comment: What menu? If you mean the Search menu you may need to do 'Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective', you may also need to do 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' and set the Search menu visibility in the 'Menu Visibility' tab.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions for clear usage of visible-when and enable-when conditions..